# Webcam Icon Invisible in My Computer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, webcam

I want to use my Webcam to take picture, but my Webcam's icon is invisible in My Computer. My Webcam's driver is already installed and my OS is Windows 7. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: which driver you installed?

Comment: @VJD, I installed Genius ILook 300's driver, its own driver.

Answer (score 1):

Not all webcam drivers include an application for taking pictures.
You can try:

- [Cameroid](http://www.cameroid.com/snap.php) - nice online tool
- [pixect](http://www.pixect.com/) - essentially the same tile Cameroid
- [CamSnap](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/Rebellious-Productions-CamSnap.shtml) - very simple software for capturing photos via webcams

Comment: no, I installed its own driver.

Comment: Ok. Driver is just software which communicates between the device (webcam) and the operating system (windows). It won't necessarily have an application for capturing photos.